# Why can't I populate an array with function call in my SwiftUI code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to populate an array `ingredients` with a function call to `networkManager.buildIngredients()` within my view but I am getting the error message `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'`. I am not too familiar with SwiftUI at the moment and I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Here is my SwiftUI struct;

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    @State var ingredients: [String]
    
    let urlString: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(networkManager.cocktails) { cocktail in

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text(cocktail.strDrink + "  -")
                        .navigationTitle("Cocktail by first letter")
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                    Text(cocktail.strAlcoholic)
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                }
                
                WebImage(url: URL(string: cocktail.strDrinkThumb))
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                
                Text("~ Ingredients List ~").frame(alignment: .center)
                
                ingredients = networkManager.buildIngredients(cocktail)
                
                ForEach(ingredients, id: \.self) { ingredient in
                    Text(ingredient)
                }
            }
        }
        
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData(urlString)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailsView(urlString: "www.google.com")
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You absolutely can, but there has to be some value when you finish initializing the struct. You can't try to initialize it in the middle of the `body` (there are some ways, but it is not recommended, and you couldn't do what you are attempting, anyway). Past that, we can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The body of a SwiftUI view is not for procedural, imperative "do this, do that" code, it's a declarative "ViewBuilder" block in which you describe the view as a value. Swift UI runtime then does the necessary imperative stuff to manage the state based on diffing the values in your views.

Comment: @Shadowrun ok so how do I call buildIngredients(_) to populate my ingredients array?

Comment: Make a ViewModel and observe it, if you're learning, try https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu lecture 3 MVVM + SwiftUI

Comment: The `body` of a SwiftUI view struct runs when data changes, but it can be unpredictable. It shouldn't have side-effects. You might benefit from getting more context about the underpinnings of Swift UI, and exactly how it's data-flow-driving architecture works. There's several WWDC videos from the past 2 years on it that would be a good place to start, IMO.